# How to add interval or condition on Z Projection on 3D Plot from Plotly (Python)?

Tags: python, plotly, projection-matrix

I'm trying to plot a matrix with a z projection but I don't want to project at each 0.5 values like below.

[image: Matrix 3D Plotting with Z Projection]

I want to project the values that are "< 7.5" for example but I don't know if it's possible with Plotly Library on Python.

If someone knows how to deal with it, I would be grateful

Here is the code I've tried:

```
    def plotIntensity3D(self):
        z = self.matrix # Numpy 2D array with values between 5.4 and 8.2

        fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=z, cmin=7,cmax=8.5)])
        # fig.update_traces(colorscale = [[0, 'rgb(255,0,0)'], [1, 'rgb(0,255,0)']])
        fig.update_traces(contours_z=dict(show=True, usecolormap=True, highlightcolor="limegreen", project_z=True))
        fig.update_layout(title='3D Light Intensity', autosize=True, width=1000, height=1000)
        
        fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add something like this to `update_layout`:

```
scene = dict(
             xaxis = dict(nticks=9, range=[0,80],),
             yaxis = dict(nticks=7, range=[0,120],),
             zaxis = dict(nticks=4, range=[5,8],),
             ),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's kinda good but the thing I want is to keep all the matrix datas and only project "on the ground" the value less than a threshold (7.5 for example).

Comment: @mafedy do I understand you correctly that you wish to plot all data that have lower value on Z axis than 7.5 to the bottom? Then I believe you should alter the data in a manner that - `if z<7.5: z=7.5` .  Please let me know if that is what you wanted, because it was not clear from the question. If you want to plot the data in "layers", then do the same for all remaining layers you wish to create, like: `if z>7.5 and z<=8.5: z=8.5` . Of course do it in your matrix.